# Windows 8 App Bar By default in app development

Tags: windows, windows-8, winjs, appbar

I want to create an app bar for my javascript app , as we know we see app bar when pressing right click , but I want it to be show by default , without right click. here is my html code

```
 <div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
    <!-- Commands for show/hide -->
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'showHideButton', label:'Show/Hide Picker', icon:'view'}">
    </button>
</div>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your app startup code, get the appbar element and call ["show()"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229676.aspx) on it.

```
// This is essentially what you need to do inside your app startup code
// After all the elements are loaded (After the WinJS.UI.processAll() I believe)
document.getElementById('appbar').show();
```

Comment: If you're bringing it up by default, there's a good chance you want it to stay up. In this case you set the app bars sticky property to true.